# SameSite attribute not set for .AspNet.Cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, httpcookie, samesite

I am working on an ASP.NET application. I'm trying to set the `samesite` attribute to `"Lax"`, but it is still showing as blank.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Upgraded .Net framework to v4.7.2 from v4.6
- Set samesite in httpcookies in web.config - `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" sameSite="Lax"/>`
- Set samesite in sessionState in web.config - `<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />`

None of these options worked. Can anyone help to identify what I am missing here?